# In C# What type interface implementation is this called

Tags: c#, terminology

If **Class A Implements Interface I1**
and **Class B inherits from A**

Then do we say that **B has implicitly inherited I1 implementation**?

`Class A : I1`

`Class B : A`

Are there any differences with

`Class B : A, I1`

Comment: @YashwanthRao : Class B inherits from and Implements I1, That is not multiple ingeritence as yes it very possible in C#,